# Python - Iterating over a list of dictionaries

Tags: python, python-3.x

So the idea in the below question is given a list of dictionaries with some values what I need is a nested dictionary of dependent nodes.

```
 Nodes = [
{
    "number": "10",
    "dependsOn": "13",
    "priority": "1649"
    "version": "1.7",
    "health": "ok"
},
{
    "number": "12",
    "dependsOn": "14",
    "priority": "2100"
    "version": "1.8",
    "health": "ok"
},
{
    "number": "3",
    "dependsOn": "2",
    "priority": "1234"
    "version": "1.1",
    "health": "ok"
}, {
    "number": "2",
    "dependsOn": "1",
    "priority": "1456",
    "version": "1.3",
    "health": "ok"
}, {
    "number": "1",
    "dependsOn": "10",
    "priority": "1890,
    "version": "1.2",
    "health": "ok"
},
{
    "number": "5",
    "dependsOn": "4",
    "priority": "1260",
    "version": "1.2",
    "health": "ok"
},
{
    "number": "4",
    "dependsOn": "12",
    "priority": "1150",
    "version": "1.4",
    "health": "ok"
}
}]
```

Expected output:

```
dependent_nodes =  { 3 : { 'dependsOn': [2,1,10,13],
                       'priority': 1234 # Lowest priority of the three
                      }, 
                  5 : { 'dependsOn': [4,12,14],
                       'priority': 1150 # Lowest priority of the three
                      }
                }
```

What would be the best way to achieve this output?

Comment: You can't use curly quotes as string delimiters in Python (or most other languages). Turn off "smart quotes" when editing code.

Comment: Good to know. Thank you @Barmar

Comment: can you post expected output?

Comment: Who do you have only 3 and 5 in your Dict ?

Comment: Looks like they want all roots in a DAG and any nodes that depend on those roots.

Comment: @Aditya.Kommu 3 and 5 is what all the nodes are dependent upon. 3 and 5 follow a graph. I would say this is a graph problem.

Comment: Why wouldn't 14 also be in the array that 5 depends on? 5 depends on 4 which depends on 12, which in turn depends on 14

Comment: @sumshyftw you are right, just added.

Answer (score 0):

Something like this should get you started. It's not optimal but you can tweak it to how you see fit with proper context.

```py
mapping = {}
for item in Nodes:
    mapping[item['number']] = (item['dependsOn'], item['priority'])

ans = {}
added = set()

for key, value in mapping.items():
    if key in added:
        continue
    if key not in ans:
        ans[key] = {'dependsOn': [], 'priority': float('Inf')}
    curr = value[0]
    priority = float(value[1])
    while True:
        ans[key]['dependsOn'].append(curr)
        added.add(curr)
        ans[key]['priority'] = min(ans[key]['priority'], priority)
        
        if curr in ans:
            ans[key]['dependsOn'] += ans[curr]['dependsOn']
            ans[key]['priority'] = min(ans[key]['priority'], ans[curr]['priority'])
            del ans[curr]
            break
        elif curr in mapping and mapping[curr][0] not in added:
            priority = float(mapping[curr][1])
            curr = mapping[curr][0]
        else:
            break
```

This will yield:

```py
{'3': {'dependsOn': ['2', '1', '10', '13'], 'priority': 1234.0},
 '5': {'dependsOn': ['4', '12', '14'], 'priority': 1150.0}}
```

Comment: Thanks @sumshyftw, trying it out.